# How to see what comments I have not read yet?

Tags: linuxfr.org

[Linuxfr.org](http://linuxfr.org) is the French equivalent of Slashdot.

For a given story, logged in users can see the number of new comments since they last visited the story. For instance, on [this story](http://linuxfr.org/users/nicolas_raoul/journaux/espionnage-la-fsf-deconseille-le-cloud-public-recommande-les-clouds-prives-bases-sur-le-libre) I see `(131 commentaires, 2 nouveaux !)` (131 comments, 2 new).

Nice to know there are 2 new comments, but **where** are these 2 new comments?

I have found one of the two, and it does not seem to be visually different from old comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tiny bottom bar with `< | >` at its right.

Press the `>` to jump to the new comments, in thread order.

[image]